# awk to filter the data of one file using another file data

Tags: awk

This is the extension of Question ([Awk: using a file to filter another one (out.tr)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062402/awk-using-a-file-to-filter-another-one-out-tr))

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$NF]; next } $NF in a' other main
```

I completely understand ($NF in a) i.e. to search last column of MainFile in array a. But What is storing in the array a[$NF], is it the last column of Other file or the complete file.

I have a other file (comma separated) and want to use 2nd column to filter the data of main file. How the command will know that a[$2] is storing the 2nd column of other file that has to store in array and will be used to filter the main file.

For e.g. if i have a MainFile that contains data like

```
Date|par|Id|Number
21-Jun|0|123000|20000
20-Jun|1|123000|20000
21-Jun|0|156000|2327
21-Jun|1|156000|500000
21-Jun|0|250000|15000
20-Jun|0|251000|15000
20-Jun|0|100000|423423
18-Jun|1|102000|30000
19-Jun|0|102000|1500
```

The Other File (id1) which is used to filter MainFile (Id)

```
date,id1,id2,id3
21Jun,123000,5665,34234
21Jun,102000,23654,324
19Jun,251000,1231,123123
```

Result for above should be

```
Date|par|Id|Number
21-Jun|0|123000|20000
20-Jun|1|123000|20000
20-Jun|0|251000|15000
18-Jun|1|102000|30000
19-Jun|0|102000|1500
```

Comment: Not clear, what is your expected output, please add that into your post too in code tags.

Comment: I am voting here for close option of this post, once you add proper sample of output with complete details I will retract it then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Expected output is updated. also corrected the explanation a bit.

Comment: please check my solution now, also try to put your sample input and sample output first time itself, try to select answers as correct answers and try to up-vote people who help you in your problem, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work, but since you don't have matching ids in 3rd columns nothing is printed with the input files you posted

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$3];next} $3 in a' filter FS='|' main
```

perhaps you meant the 2nd column of the filter (id1 field), then change to

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next} $3 in a' filter FS='|' main
```

you'll get

```
21-Jun|0|123000|20000
20-Jun|1|123000|20000
20-Jun|0|251000|15000
18-Jun|1|102000|30000
19-Jun|0|102000|1500
```

perhaps to add the header

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next} FNR==1 || $3 in a' filter FS='|' main

Date|par|Id|Number
21-Jun|0|123000|20000
20-Jun|1|123000|20000
20-Jun|0|251000|15000
18-Jun|1|102000|30000
19-Jun|0|102000|1500
```